# Expand and collapse winform

Tags: c#, winforms

What I am trying to do is expand and collapse the middle of my winform. I know there are similar questions here but none of them really do what I need. I have read about using a `FlowLayoutPanel` but I can't get it to work.

An example of what I want to achieve is:

I have my winform (example)

[image: example]

When I click `button1` it should hide the textbox in the middle and shrink the form to hide the space, and vice versa when I click `button2`. Either way, `button3` should remain below where the textbox is or isn't shown.

My attempts so far either just hide the textbox and do nothing with the form or shrink a lot more than it should. I have currently been setting `AutoSize` to `true` and `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`.

I have seen controls that can do this or similar but they have arrows or little buttons to expand the form, I just need the button to do this.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Any help appreciated.

**Update**

I have tried setting the height to 0 and hiding the textbox as suggested but it just collapses the right side of the form instead of the middle.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: set the height property to 0 and hide it?
use the height you know it is to subtract from the y coordinate of where the third button is placed, and take away the height of the textbox from the forms y size, to shrink accordingly. just add them back on when you want to show it

Comment: I recently wrote something similar to this and found several examples on the net already. Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53318/C-Custom-Control-Featuring-a-Collapsible-Panel or http://collapsiblepanel.codeplex.com/releases/view/25409 for example. There are also plenty of third party controls that do this; DevExpress have a collapsible panel control. You can emulate the click event of the panel header from your button (and not show the panel header!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the original height of the form in a variable so that you can restore it later when you expand it again.  Also, if you anchor Button3 to the bottom, you wouldn't have to handle it during the resize:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  private int originalHeight;

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    button3.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
  }

  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    originalHeight = this.Height;
    base.OnLoad(e);
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Visible = false;
    this.Height = originalHeight - textBox1.Height;
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Height = originalHeight;
    textBox1.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

Leave the `AutoSize=false;` on the form since you are handling the resize yourself.

I would consider using one button to handle the toggling of the form since Button2 is rather useless when the form is expanded and vice-versa, Button1 is rather useless if the form is collapsed.

Comment: Thats BRILLIANT! :) Exactly what I was looking for. I will do the toggling on 1 button as you suggested, which is much better, thanks ever so much!

Comment: Although this method works, I believe this is a terrible way of achieving what you want. Any change on the layout would require plenty of code changes, and introducing otherwise useless variables. (Not saying it's not the answer to your question: it is... it's just a very bad way of doing it)

Answer (score 2):

I know, I am late to the game but since I just solved the same issue I wanted to provide you with my solution:

As you mentioned already, you can use `FlowLayoutPanel` to do the job. Just put it into your form. Set the FlowDirection to `TopDown` and add your buttons and textbox in the right order. 
When done, set the `AutoSize` of the form and the FlowLayoutPanel to true and set the `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`.

**Prevent the width to collapse when autosize on**

Your problem is, that if you set the AutoSize to true and disable/hide your textbox, the width is going to be reduced. This happens because your textbox is the widest control on your form and if it is hidden, the width is reduced to the width required by the remaining controls. To prevent this happening, just put your buttons into a panel control of the same width as your textbox. 
Now if your textbox is hidden, the width will remain as wide as required.

**Using checkbox to expand/collapse**

Instead of using two buttons, I like using a checkbox to expand/collapse. The whole coding for resizing will be reduced to adding one binding line of the `checkbox1.Checked` property to the `Visibility` property of the textbox:

> textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Visible", checkbox1, "Checked")

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done using panels and docking. Using `AutoSize` is the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the control and set the Height property accordingly.